# tinymce, automatically add style attribute to content

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce-4

I'm working on a project that uses tinymce as RTF editor where users insert formatted content that will be saved as text as is. With all HTML tags becouse the content will be used in varous parts as HTML.

I'd like that all generated HTML elements have a default style attribute, something like:

```
<p style="margin: 0 10px; line-height: 1">
    Hello World
</p>
<h1 style="margin: 0 10px; line-height: 1">
    Hello World Again
</h1>
```

I've tried to add `content_style: "* { margin: 0 10px, line-height: 1 }"` to tinymceOptions but it doesn't works

Comment: Does this help? [Custom format demo](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/format-custom/)

Comment: I saw also `style_formats` but this creates custom formats that the user have to select by Formats dropdown. Could be a workaround if I don't find alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has no built in way to force all block elements to have a pre-defined set of styles.  TinyMCE does fire a variety of events when things happen in the editor (e.g. inserting content, a new block is created, a key is pressed) and you could use those to try to identify any time a new block is being placed in the editor and add your styles.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows some events in action:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2fgaab

The hard part here is that there are lots of ways to modify what is in the editor and to get this 100% right you need to catch all those events/activities.

The alternative is to do this when the content is submitted to the server and iterate over the block elements at that time.